# Don't understand recursive function's output

Tags: python, recursion

```
def some_func(count):
    if count > 0:
        some_func(count-1)
        print(count)

print(some_func(5))
```

The output is

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

In my understanding, The function will be reduced to some_func(0) and print 0 as the final output. But the actual output is from 1 to 5? What's happening with each iteration?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in the if condition you set `count > 0` it will never enter this block if `count` is `0` then it will not print `0`

Comment: But where did the 1, 2, 3,4,5 come from? In the first iteration the count should be 5 no?

Comment: I am confused about whether your last statement `print(some_func(5))` is inside the function or not. It doesn't really make sense since the function doesn't return anything.

Comment: it run everything in the function first(which is nested functions of `some_func(4), some_func(3), some_func(2), some_func(1)` ) before printing out the parent count number. so it print out the final child and came back to the parent functions. you can't print out 0 as you set `count > 0` so it can only reach 1

Comment: @LinhNguyen so the output of some_func(4) is 1? How does this work? I am really confused

Comment: @JiangYuxin this will helps how recursion works https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/

Comment: @Jiang Yuxin, somefunc(4) has somefunc(3) in it has somefunc(2) and finally somefunc(1), so it will run from child function which is somefunc(1) and come back to the top

Comment: @st4rgut the print statement not necessary as some_func(5) already used print, so he just printed the result twice

Comment: `print(some_func(5))` should print `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly there is the problem of indentation here please correct that and adding a little white space at the end of function makes things clear.

```py
def some_func(count):
    if count > 0:
        some_func(count-1)
        print(count)
        
print(some_func(5))
```

The reason is, in recursion the code next to the recursive call is put into a stack memory which is a Last in First Out structure, you can find more about it here [stack](https://www.javatpoint.com/data-structure-stack) and until the termination condition for the code comes up the pushes of subsequent statements keep happening on to the top of the stack.
A sample visualization of what happens after you call the `print(some_func(5))`

1. `print(some_func(5))`:
   5>0 => True, so the next cmd some_func(5-1) is called at this point something interesting happens, in the stack space all the subsequent statements of `some_func(count-1)` are pushed and then the actual method invocation starts, so at this point in time the stack will look like this:

```
| TOP_OF_STACK |
|--------------|
| print(5)     |
```

2. Next line to get invoked is some_func(4):
   then again 4>0 => True
   so some_func(4-1) is called and the subsequent print(4) is pushed on to the stack as shown below:

```
| TOP_OF_STACK |
|--------------|
| print(4)     |
|--------------|
| print(5)     |
```

3. some_func(3):
   3>0 => True,
   call some_func(3-1) and push print(3) on to the top of the stack.

```
| TOP_OF_STACK |
|--------------|
| print(3)     |
|--------------|
| print(4)     |
|--------------|
| print(5)     |
```

Same thing goes on for some_func(2) and some_func(1) by the end of which stack looks like this:

```
| TOP_OF_STACK |
|--------------|
| print(1)     |
|--------------|
| print(2)     |
|--------------|
| print(3)     |
|--------------|
| print(4)     |
|--------------|
| print(5)     |
```

When some_func(0) is called the following thign happens:
0>0 => false so no further statements following if will be called and all the statements that have been pushed on to the stack so far will be popped out sequentially from the top, which results in the execution of the print statements resulting in the output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Additionally one possible reason why you may encounter stack overflow errors for recursive code sometimes is because if your terminal condition is not a valid one then the pushes keep on happening until a point there is no space left out in the memory!

Hope this gives you better understanding of the recursive flow.

Comment: Wow never learnt this in class! Thank you so much! Does this last in first out structure only exist in recursive functions?

Comment: You may wanna look at stack and heap memory allocation [here] (https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/how-does-memory-allocation-work-in-python-and-other-languages-d2d8a9398543). And you can also learn about Data Structures in brief over [here] (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-structures/).

Answer (score 4):

Note the order of statement execution!

```
some_func(5)
-- some_func(4)
---- some_func(3)
------ some_func(2)
-------- some_func(1)
---------- some_func(0)
---------- print(1)
-------- print(2)
------ print(3)
---- print(4)
-- print(5)
```

In `some_func(0)`, the condition `0>0` is not satisfied, hence `some_func` and `print(0)` function call is skipped.